# How do I make react input show state value-ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, state

By using class, here is a small ref for all of you :

```
Class ShowValue Extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: “ “,
        }
    }
    onChangeHandler = (e) => {
        this.setState(
            name: e.target.value,
        )
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <input type=” text” onChange={this.onChangeHandler} value=” My name”>
                <p>{this.state.name}</p>
        ); 
    } 
}
```

Am I able to create a variable for each input field, and listening on the onChange event and then call the “set” function for that variable by using hooks.

Comment: Do you mean using multi inputs?

Comment: Viet, it's like a submission form with span of input field(s).

Comment: I think you should describe your issue in more detail

Comment: Viet, if allowed, I'll update surely.

Comment: You can't use hooks in a class component.

Comment: Nagy, In the near future, React Hooks can potentially replace class components. I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your code, now if you write in the input text it will be saved in your state name or vice-versa if you write in your code something in state name it will appear in the input.

I recommend you to check some tutorials or even the official doc

```
import React from 'react';

class ShowValue extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: ''
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          value={this.state.name}
          type="text"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <p>{this.state.name}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ShowValue;
```

**Have in mind:**

- You need to write a parent element to return different child elements otherwise it will give you error. So i've wrapped the input and p element.
- You can not use `”` for strings in javascript single quotes or double quotes
  `'` or `"`

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j4a4dv?file=src%2FShowValue.js

Comment: if nothing works, We think reading stuff is the best shot at solving all of these problems. I think you’ll like it.

Comment: does my answer solves your problem?  @xKodian Don't forget to mark it as useful

Comment: I thank you for your re-work on my question but I must say this didn't work as expected.

Comment: no problem, @xKodian so, could you improve your question, give more details

Answer (score 0):

Show the value inside the input by setting the value property of input

```
<input value={this.state.name} type=”text” onChange={this.onChangeHandler} >
```

Comment: an input will get set to this.state.name dynamically.

Comment: i didn't understand your comment. does my answer solves your problem?

Comment: sorry to say but not.